# Application insights not generated for .Net core app deployed on service fabric Linux cluster

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net core application that is deployed on service fabric Linux cluster. Application insights are configured in the app.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {            
            ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions
                = new ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
                {
                    EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,

                    EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false,

                    InstrumentationKey = "xxx"
                };

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

I have a **controller** class that has some action methods and logs the information.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult actionMethod(...)
       {
            TraceLine("------------------------------------");
            //some code
       }

private static void TraceLine(string msg)
        {
            msg = $">> {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")}: {msg}";
            Log.Information(msg);
        }
```

I am using Serilog, configured in appsettings.json & Program.cs

When I hit action method directly from local (without hosting it on even local sf cluster), via Postman, I see app insights getting generated and pushed to azure.

[azure app insights snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RLNL.png)

But when I hit the action method that is deployed on Azure service fabric I don't see any insight getting generated.

What am I missing here?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need to check a few things here:

1) The app insights URL and the instrumentation key in the deployment parameter files for cluster hosted on cloud (**Cloud.xml**)

2) After checking the Cloud.xml, the best way is to access the log files and check what is the actual problem.

There's a description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#check-your-running-application) which explains how to discover where the log files are stored.

You can use RDP to access the machine, which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cloud.xml looks fine. Accessing RDP just shows DOS cmd prompt. And I don't really know what to do with the dos prompt.

Comment: I was to able to solve this issue & have posted the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using *Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native* SDK in my application to log app insights.

Refer .NetCore section in [ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric/blob/master/README.md#net-core-1) on how to configure insights for service fabric application.